# Magento 1 After enable formkey on checkout page not go next from payment method

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, payment-methods

I have checked formkey is available on all checkout pages but on frontend checkout page payment step continue button not working.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have added the some code into `skin/frontend/<package>/<theme>/js/opcheckout.js` line number around 714 and it's working.

Before I added code the code like this

```
if (elements[i].name=='payment[method]') {
```

I added form key into if condition

```
if (elements[i].name=='payment[method]' || elements[i].name == 'form_key') {
```

It's work for me.

Comment: The above code will comes with default patch code

Comment: but in my js there is only  `if (elements[i].name=='payment[method]') {` code is written.

Comment: I manually add form_key code.

Comment: Ok anyawy its worked

Answer (score 2):

Its May be the issue with formkey: Please check the formkeys with theme checkout files

patch 9767 adds form keys to the following forms:

**Shipping cart form:**

```
app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
```

**Multishipping billing checkout form:**

```
app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml
```

**Multishipping shipping checkout form:**

```
app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/multishipping/shipping.phtml
```

**Billing checkout form:**

```
app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
```

**Shipping checkout form:**

```
app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
```

**Payment checkout form:**

```
app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
```

**Shipping method checkout form:**

```
app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method.phtml
```

**Persistent Billing checkout form:**

```
app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
```

What to do:

If you're using with custom versions of those templates you'll have to update them by adding the following code into them:
getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>

thanks

Comment: I have check all phtml files which you listed above and I found form key in all files.

Comment: and form key is within form

Comment: check your theme files

Comment: I check phtml files.  I found <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?> in all files

Comment: Follow this link:https://gist.github.com/schmengler/c42acc607901a887ef86b4daa7a0445b

Comment: No I have install patch without ssh.

Comment: copy the file and paste in your root folder. then
sh add-checkout-form-key.sh in you terminal

Comment: Thanks for the support but I have found one solution and it's work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/190097/1883) is the correct one.

For other people, who are having form issues on checkout page after implementing Magento PATCH SUPEE-9767, here is a patch that solves the form key issue on checkout page. Very helpful if you are using a custom theme.

https://gist.github.com/schmengler/c42acc607901a887ef86b4daa7a0445b